# MongoDB Aggregate Time Series

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm using MongoDB to store time series data using a similar structure to "The Document-Oriented Design" explained here: http://blog.mongodb.org/post/65517193370/schema-design-for-time-series-data-in-mongodb

The objective is to query for the top 10 busiest minutes of the day on the whole system.  Each document stores 1 hour of data using 60 sub-documents (1 for each minute).  Each minute stores various metrics embedded in the "vals" field.  The metric I care about is "orders".  A sample document looks like this:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("54d023802b1815b6ef7162a4"),
        "user" : "testUser",
        "hour" : ISODate("2015-01-09T13:00:00Z"),
        "vals" : {
                "0" : {
                        "orders" : 11,
                        "anotherMetric": 15
                },
                "1" : {
                        "orders" : 12,
                        "anotherMetric": 20
                },
                .
                .
                .
        }
}
```

Note there are many users in the system.

I've managed to flatten the structure (somewhat) by doing an aggregate with the following group object:

```
group = {
    $group: {
        _id: {
            hour: "$hour"
        },
        0: {$sum: "$vals.0.orders"},
        1: {$sum: "$vals.1.orders"},
        2: {$sum: "$vals.2.orders"},
        .
        .
        .
    }
}
```

But that just gives me 24 documents (1 for each hour) with the # of orders for each minute during that hour, like so:

```
{
    "_id" : {
            "hour" : ISODate("2015-01-20T14:00:00Z")
    },
    "0" : 282086,
    "1" : 239358,
    "2" : 289188,
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Now I need to somehow get the top 10 minutes of the day from this but I'm not sure how.  I suspect it can be done with $project, but I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could aggregate as:

- `$match` the documents for the specific date.
- Construct the `$group` and `$project` objects before querying.
- `$group` by the `$hour`, accumulate all the documents per hour per
  minute in an array.Keep the minute somewhere within the document.
- `$project` a variable docs as `$setUnion` of all the documents per
  hour.
- `$unwind` the documents.
- `$sort` by `orders`
- `$limit` the top `10` documents which is what we require.

Code:

```
var inputDate = new ISODate("2015-01-09T13:00:00Z");
var group = {};
var set = [];
for(var i=0;i<=60;i++){
    group[i] = {$push:{"doc":"$vals."+i,
                       "hour":"$_id.hour",
                       "min":{$literal:i}}};
    set.push("$"+i);
}
group["_id"] = {$hour:"$hour"};
var project = {"docs":{$setUnion:set}}

db.t.aggregate([
{$match:{"hour":{$lte:inputDate,$gte:inputDate}}},
{$group:group},
{$project:project},
{$unwind:"$docs"},
{$sort:{"docs.doc.orders":-1}},
{$limit:2},
{$project:{"_id":0,
           "hour":"$_id",
           "doc":"$docs.doc",
           "min":"$docs.min"}}
])
```

Comment: This strategy does it.  Your for loop iterates 1 time too many, but the concept itself works.  Thanks!